# Disk Utility - 3 Pass Erase

Tags: disk-utility, secure-erase

Just for my curiosity and knowledge,

I read on a book that Disk Utility can erase a Volume/Partition by using different option of security.

Among these options there is one called: 3 Pass Erase, that writes two passes of random data followed by a single pass of known data to the disk.

According to Apple, this option meets **US Department of Energy**.  What does the **US Department of Energy** have to do with secure erasing data? Do they control the security standard? I thought was the Department of Defense that control the standards.

Thank you

Comment: Got a link to that source please?

Comment: Book - OS X Support Essentials 10.9 - Supporting and Troubleshooting OS X Maveriks

Answer (score 1):

The 3 pass erase method, where two passes are random data and one is known data is listed in DoE M 205.1-6. The DoE among their other sensitive operations, designs, tests, and builds the US nuclear arsenal. Different agencies often develop different methods to achieve same results.

Also, I don't think either agency uses either of those methods anymore.